# Entities field length constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, constraints, maxlength

I'm currently working with Entities (using visual studio 2008, FW 3.5 SP1).
I created my entities from the database, and everything is ok, except that my length constraints on the string fields are not enforced.
Browsing the internet, I found out that this is quite normal (see this [blog post](http://blog.alner.net/archive/2010/04/13/entity_framework_does_not_enforce_maxlength_metadata.aspx)), and that Entities sends the data without check to the database, to possibly send exceptions.

I know I could write partial classes for my entities, and use the `On<Fieldname>Changing` methods, but this would require quite an amount of repetitive code to be written.  Moreover 
if I change a length in the DB, this would require me to change my code as well.

So my question is: Is there a generic way to to this ? Is it possible, for each data type which has a maximum length to check if the provided value is fitting ?

Comment: My first question would be, what are you going to do if the value doesn't fit?  If you're going to throw an exception, then I would say, what's the point?  You can just let the database throw the exception.

Comment: Yes, that's what I plan to do (and convert the exception into a FaultException, to go through WCF).  The problem is that I've read that the exception thrown by the database is a generic one (with text inside explaining what failed).  I want to be able to treat the exception depending on its type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I didn't find a way to do this in a generic way, I finally wrote all `On<Fieldname>Changing` methods, and made a small generic verification framework, which throws exceptions when some criteria is not met.